# Suppose 5 fair coins are tossed simultaneously. What is the probablity of getting a various number of heads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose 5 fair coins are tossed simultaneously. What is probablity of getting

1. No heads.
2. Precisely 1 head.
3. At least 1 head.
4. No more than 4 heads.

Let $x$ be the random variable.

Kindly I need answers in Combination formula. i.e, $\frac{n!}{k! (n - k)!}  p^k q ^ {n - k} .. $

I had done through simple logical, as  total outcomes = 32, so no head Probability is $\frac{1}{32}$, precisely one head can be achieved by $\frac{5}{32}$ .

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, it doesn't matter if you throw them simultaneously or one at a time

1) No heads

$P_1=0.5^5$

2) Precisely 1 head

$P_2=\binom{5}{1}*0.5^5$

3) At least 1 head

$P_3=1-P_1=1-0.5^5$

4) No more than 4 heads

$P_4=1-P_5=1-0.5^5$, where $P_5$ is the probability of getting 5 heads.

Edit: i can give you types for example: N coins and exactly m heads, but i will let you  search it first by looking at my answers